# Display Template Error: The processing of item fails with error > Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: 2013, display-template

I created a very basic display template to show some properties for a content type,
Basically it says, if content type ="Tax Invoice", use this diplay template.

All the managed properties exist and are correctly spelled.

The only thing I can think of is maybe some of them might be empty or null and I need to write javascript logic for that?

If you think that might be the reason, can you please show me an example for my display template below.

```
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"> 
<head>
<title>Item Tax Invoice</title>

<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:TemplateHidden msdt:dt="string">0</mso:TemplateHidden>
<mso:MasterPageDescription msdt:dt="string">Displays the default result item template.</mso:MasterPageDescription>
<mso:ContentTypeId msdt:dt="string">0xxx</mso:ContentTypeId>
<mso:TargetControlType msdt:dt="string">;#SearchResults;#</mso:TargetControlType>
<mso:HtmlDesignAssociated msdt:dt="string">1</mso:HtmlDesignAssociated>
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'Title':'Title','Path':'Path','Description':'Description','EditorOWSUSER':'EditorOWSUSER','LastModifiedTime':'LastModifiedTime','CollapsingStatus':'CollapsingStatus','DocId':'DocId','HitHighlightedSummary':'HitHighlightedSummary','HitHighlightedProperties':'HitHighlightedProperties','FileExtension':'FileExtension','ViewsLifeTime':'ViewsLifeTime','ParentLink':'ParentLink','FileType':'FileType','IsContainer':'IsContainer','SecondaryFileExtension':'SecondaryFileExtension','DisplayAuthor':'DisplayAuthor','JobCodes':'JobCodes','BillNumber':'BillNumber','BillDate':'BillDate','BillToDate':'BillToDate','Amount':'Amount','DueDate':'DueDate'</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>
<mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded msdt:dt="string">True</mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded>
<mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview msdt:dt="string">https://be-xx.xx.x.xx.com/sites/billing/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Item_TaxInvoice.html, Conversion successful.</mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview>
<mso:CrawlerXSLFile msdt:dt="string"></mso:CrawlerXSLFile>
<mso:HtmlDesignPreviewUrl msdt:dt="string"></mso:HtmlDesignPreviewUrl>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Item_TaxInvoice">
<!--#_ 
        if(!$isNull(ctx.CurrentItem) && !$isNull(ctx.ClientControl)){
            var id = ctx.ClientControl.get_nextUniqueId();
            var itemId = id + Srch.U.Ids.item;
            var hoverId = id + Srch.U.Ids.hover;
            var hoverUrl = "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Item_Word_HoverPanel.js";
              $setResultItem(itemId, ctx.CurrentItem);
            if(ctx.CurrentItem.IsContainer){
                ctx.CurrentItem.csr_Icon = Srch.U.getFolderIconUrl();
            }
            ctx.currentItem_ShowHoverPanelCallback = Srch.U.getShowHoverPanelCallback(itemId, hoverId, hoverUrl);
            ctx.currentItem_HideHoverPanelCallback = Srch.U.getHideHoverPanelCallback();
            var dueDate = new Date($getItemValue(ctx, "DueDate"));
            var billDate = new Date($getItemValue(ctx, "BillDate"));

_#-->
            <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(itemId) =#_" name="Item" data-displaytemplate="TaxInvoiceItem" class="ms-srch-item" onmouseover="_#= ctx.currentItem_ShowHoverPanelCallback =#_" onmouseout="_#= ctx.currentItem_HideHoverPanelCallback =#_">
                _#=ctx.RenderBody(ctx)=#_
                <p><b>Jobs: </b> _#= ctx.CurrentItem.JobCodes= #_ </p>
                <p><b>Bill Number: </b> _#= ctx.CurrentItem.BillNumber =#_ </p>
                <p><b>Bill date: </b>_#= billDate.format("dd/MM/yyyy") =#_  </p>
                <p><b>Bill To Date: </b> _#= billToDate.format("dd/MM/yyyy") =#_ </p>
                <p><b>Amount: </b> _#= ctx.CurrentItem.Amount =#_ </p>
                <p><b>Due date: </b> _#= dueDate.format("dd/MM/yyyy") =#_ </p>
                <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(hoverId) =#_" class="ms-srch-hover-outerContainer"></div>
            </div>

<!--#_ 
        } 
_#-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> Component and System=Query1-cbdbeb60-6b87-4f94-8bfa-7ed8baf7a3c1,
>   Correlation ID=9d06819c-4647-c05e-bf84-fd27fad8a135, Tenant
>   ID=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 Error code=, Flow
>   Name=Microsoft.SharePointSearchProviderFlow, Operator
>   Name=ParserExecutor, Message=The processing of item fails with error
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Component.FlowHandleRegistry :
>   Exceptions occurred when evaluating the flow. 
>   Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.DataModel.EvaluationException: Evaluation
>   failed in operator IndexLookupExecutor of type IndexLookupExecutor
>   ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.      at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Processing.DisplayResults.RetrieveRecords(IList`1
>   docIds, IList`1 fieldsList, IQueryPipelineService
>   queryPipelineService, IMarsLookupService lookup, Int64 generationId,
>   Int64 timeout, Guid correlationId, Guid tenantId, Guid
>   siteCollectionId, String docIdFieldName)      at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Processing.ResultTypeCalculatorEvaluator.ResultTypeCalculatorRecordSet.RetrieveDisplayFields(Guid
>   correlationId, Guid searchApplicationId)      at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Processing.ResultTypeCalculatorEvaluator.ResultTypeCalculatorRecordSet.DoMoveNext()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.RecordSets.RecordSet.MoveNext() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.RecordSets.RecordSet.d__0.MoveNext()
>   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)      at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)      at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Executors.IndexLookupExecutor.ExecuteCore(IRecord
>   inputRecord)      at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Executors.QueryPipelineFlowExecutor.Execute(IRecord
>   inputRecord)      at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Processing.ExecutorProducer`1.ProcessRecord(IRecord
>   record)      at
>   Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.Put(IRecord
>   record)      at
>   Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Engine.ErrorHandling.HandleExceptionRecordSetSink.DoWithoutTryCatch(IRecord
>   record)      at
>   Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.PushToOutput()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.Put(IRecord
>   record)      at
>   Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Engine.ErrorHandling.HandleExceptionRecordSetSink.DoWithoutTryCatch(IRecord
>   record)      at
>   Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.PushToOutput()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.Put(IRecord
>   record)      at
>   Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Engine.ErrorHandling.HandleExceptionRecordSetSink.DoWithoutTryCatch(IRecord
>   record)      at
>   Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.PushToOutput()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.Put(IRecord
>   record)      at
>   Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Engine.ErrorHandling.HandleExceptionRecordSetSink.DoWithoutTryCatch(IRecord
>   record)      at
>   Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.PushToOutput()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.Put(IRecord
>   record)      at
>   Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Engine.ErrorHandling.HandleExceptionRecordSetSink.DoWithoutTryCatch(IRecord
>   record)      at
>   Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.PushToOutput()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.Put(IRecord
>   record)      at
>   Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Engine.Aborting.AbortableRecordSetSink.Put(IRecord
>   record)      at
>   Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Engine.ErrorHandling.HandleExceptionRecordSetSink.DoWithTryCatch(IRecord
>   record)     -  -- End of inner exception stack trace ---      at
>   Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Engine.ErrorHandling.HandleExceptionRecordSetSink.DoWithTryCatch(IRecord
>   record)      at
>   Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Component.FlowHandleRegistry.SubmitData(FlowExecutionInfo
>   handle, InputData inputData, Stopwatch timer, String correlationId,
>   Guid tenantId, String query, String flowName, Int32
>   queryTimeoutMillis)      at
>   Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Component.FlowHandleRegistry.ExecuteFlow(String
>   flowName, InputData input, Int32 queryTimeoutMillis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p><b>Bill To Date: </b> _#= billToDate.format("dd/MM/yyyy") =#_ </p>
```

this property (billToDate) is never mentioned before!

You have missed:

```
var billToDate = new Date($getItemValue(ctx, "BillToDate"));
```

Comment: thanks for noticing that, I changed that, but not difference yet. still the same error on the logs.

Comment: please note some fields are not mandatory, so I guess that is the reason, I believe dueDate.format will throw that error if duedate is empty

Comment: I think I am right, but how can I check if the value is an Invalid Date?  please see this: http://screencast.com/t/C7ZhcyPT

Comment: First check for null/emtpy (use: $isNull or $isEmptyString) before parsing it as a Date object. If you have multiple cultures to deal with use ctx.CurrentCultureName along with moment.js and then proceed with parsing the respective format.